# Nested SQL query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I am trying to run the following sql query:

```
select *
from fblikes
order by likes desc (select * from fblikes order by id asc limit 0,4)
```

it gives the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(select * from fblikes order by id asc limit 0,4) LIMIT 0, 30'
>   at line 1

what i want to achieve is that the query should select first 5 entries by 'id' (ascending) and out of those 5 it should order them by 'likes' (descending).

I am poor at nested queries. Any Help?

Comment: @fthella thanks for the edit. I'll take care to properly edit the question from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
(
   select * 
   from fblikes 
   order by id asc 
   limit 0,4
) AS Sub
order by likes desc ;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Will accept this as the correct answer once the timeoff ends! Cheers!